# Collapse fragment on second time TextView is clicked. Shows fragment onClick, but doesn't hide it on 2nd click

Tags: java, android

I have an `Activity` page with 4 different elements that are fragments which I have created containers for under their respective titles. `OnClick` I want the fragment to open and another click on it's title and I would like for that fragment to close.

For some reason, the code that I have written is opening the fragment just as it is supposed to right beneath the title, but the second click on the title which is supposed to close/hide/collapse the fragment isn't doing so.

I wasn't sure if I should be looking for the container in `findViewById` or the actual fragment name... Makes sense for it to be the actual container and not the fragment name.

What should I modify to make this work?

**SettingsActivity**

```
mPrivacy.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_privacy, new PrivacyFragment(), null).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_privacy);
            if (fragment != null)
                if (fragment.isVisible()) {
                    fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment).commit();
                } else {
                    fragmentTransaction.show(fragment).commit();
                }
        });

        mSecurity.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //Create Security Fragment
        });

        mHelp.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //Create Help Fragment
        });

        mAbout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //Create About Fragment
        });

        getUserInfo();
    }
```

I've also been trying it like this, but still won't close after it's opened.

**Second method**

```
 mPrivacy.setOnClickListener(v -> {


   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_privacy, new PrivacyFragment(), null).addToBackStack(null);
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_privacy);
    if (fragment != null) {
        if (fragment.isHidden()) {
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment);
        }
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
});
```

This last method actually works and does what I want it to do, but just wondering if it's a good way to go about it. Have seen some posts that say not to mess with the `Visibility`. Was wondering why? Does it matter?

**Third method**

```
mPrivacy.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_privacy, new PrivacyFragment(), null).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            if (mFrameLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest solution I've found. Try to place the fragment in a **FrameLayout** and simply show/hide the **FrameLayout**

```
            <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/frame_id"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <fragment
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: But it has to respond to the click. If I click on the title it has to appear the container with the contents of the fragment and if I hit it again it has to close

Comment: OnClickListener: `FrameLayout frameLayout= 
                            findViewById(R.id.frame_id);
                            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: Wrap setVisibility with `if (frameLayout.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE)` to set accordingly

Comment: `if (frameLayout != null) {
            if (frameLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            
            } else if (frameLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }`

Comment: This works just fine... I was trying not to use Visibility because I've seen some posts that say to avoid it. Not sure why apparently hide and show have that built in. Anyways, thanks for the response!